# Django/Python - AssertionError: Class ThreadSerializer missing "Meta.model" attribute

Tags: python, django, request, postman

I've been trying to build the backend of a forum board for a mobile application and I've been running into an issue when trying to test the API endpoints over Postman. It says that my ThreadSerializer class is missing the "Meta.model" attribute.

#### My serializer code:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from forum.models import Thread
from forum.models import Post

class ThreadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        Thread_Model = Thread
        Thread_Fields = ['id', 'thread_id', 'title', 'desc', 'created_at']


class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        Post_Model = Post
        Post_Fields = ['id', 'post_id', 'post_content', 'post_time', 'thread_id']
```

`Model code ---`

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from Authentication.models import User
# Create your models here.
class Thread(models.Model):
    userid = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    thread_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    desc = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    
class Post(models.Model):
    userid = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    thread_id = models.ForeignKey(Thread, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    post_content = models.TextField()
    post_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Any advice on how to fix this?

This is the error I got on VSC:
[image: Error VSC]

and Postman:
[image: Error Postman]

Answer (score 0):

change

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from forum.models import Thread
from forum.models import Post

class ThreadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        Thread_Model = Thread
        Thread_Fields = ['id', 'thread_id', 'title', 'desc', 'created_at']


class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        Post_Model = Post
        Post_Fields = ['id', 'post_id', 'post_content', 'post_time', 'thread_id']
```

to:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from forum.models import Thread
from forum.models import Post

class ThreadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        model = Thread
        fields = ['id', 'thread_id', 'title', 'desc', 'created_at']


class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['id', 'post_id', 'post_content', 'post_time', 'thread_id']
```